# Buy one get one 50% off

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I am trying to set up a `Buy 1 Get 1 50% off promotion` only for one brand that we sell - New Balance. I can get it to apply the discount but it does it to all New Balance products in the cart. I need it to apply only to one of them - preferably the lower value of the two.

Should I use (in actions) "`Buy X get Y free`" and set Y to the discount amount?

Or should I use "Percent of product price discount"?

The other issue is how to have it apply to only one of the two products in the cart.

Comment: If you prefer third-party solutions for this kind of conditions, I suggest using the Special Promotions Pro (https://goo.gl/jYPgcS) from Amasty.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and came up with an alternate solution that I feel workes as most expect it to.  The overall concept is for every 1 item that is a purchased the buyer can get a 2nd item (in our case exact same item) for 50% off.  If the item costs $100 a qty of 2 items would show as $150 in the cart after the coupon was applied. It gets a little tricky when you go to an odd number of items. Using the same $100 item what happens if the visitor wants to buy 3.  We believed the correct answer is The 1st Item is $100.  The 2nd Item is 50% off or $50.  The first item is again $100 for a total of $250.  If the visitor buys 4 then the total is $300.  You only get one item at 50% for each full price item that is purchased.  We tried setting up our coupon as mentioned by Vishwas Bhatnagar.  However, we were not getting the correct total for any quantity.  So we looked at a little differently.  We viewed the concept of buy 1 at full price get the second at 50% as a 25% discount provided you buy and even number of the same item.

The math to support this is
2 X 100 = 200 (total regular price)
100+50) = 150 (total discount price)
200 - 150 = 50 (the dollar value of the discount)
50 / 200 = 25% (percentage discount for order)

So what we did to support and get the correct discount amount applied was to use the following setup on the ACTIONS tab:

Apply = Percent of product price discount
Discount Amount = 25
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To = 0 (we did not want to limit the qty)
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) = 2 (The discount only applied to sets of 2)
Apply to Shipping = NO
Free Shipping = NO
Stop Further Rules Process = YES (we did not want to allow this to combined with other discount codes)

We then added a ruled to the Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions.  For the rule to apply there had to be at least a qty of 2 for the row in the cart
if ALL of these conditions are TRUE 
   Row total in cart: equals or greter than 2

The above produced the correct discount amounts for our situation

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your `Actions` tab you'll notice that your conditions are:

- `If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:`
- `Quantity in cart is 2`

Which is why it is only applied if there are a quantity of 2 of the same product. There's a great guide available on http://www.magentocommerce.com over here

```
Apply: Percent of product price discount
Discount Amount: 50
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 2
Apply to Shipping Amount: No
Free Shipping: No
Stop Further Rules Processing: No

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
SKU is YOUR_SKU
```

Comment: By default, Magento 1/2 does not support this kind of promotions. I suggest that you try the Special Promotions Pro (https://goo.gl/jYPgcS) from Amasty. Special Promotions Pro really works well for our needs and for this kind of instances.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento 1 does not support this kind of promotions. I suggest that you try the [Special Promotions Pro](https://goo.gl/jYPgcS) from Amasty. Special Promotions Pro really works well for our needs and for this kind of instances.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.foowebs.com/p134-Magento--How-to-Get-Buy-One-Get-One-Half-Off-To-Work

Try this, Also define the category in the actions tab so that it works for that specific category

Comment: A link only answer is not really good practice as the link could change or be deleted. Please try to write the answer in here.

Comment: Got it, i'll keep it in mind next time.